# Auto tuning PID for a UGV using ros and python

Tags: python, machine-learning, ros, pid

I want to program my UGV with two wheels running on brushless DC motors and skid steering configuration to go in a straight line.I want to autotune the PID to find best gains to nullify the deviation in straight line path of the bot. Currently I am using ROS and a simple_pid package to tune the bot. However I want to find a way to automatically find he best gains for the bot using any method. Can someone point me to the right resources or guide me as to how I can go about this? My existing code is as follows

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import rospy
#PACKAGE = 'mypkg'
#import roslib;roslib.load_manifest(PACKAGE)
from std_msgs.msg import Int32MultiArray,Float32
import dynamic_reconfigure.client
import time
from simple_pid import PID



class PID_tuning():

    def __init__(self):

        self.sbus_throttle = 1125
        self.sbus_steering = 1024
        self.sbus_steering_limit = 300
        self.sbus_steering_min = self.sbus_steering - self.sbus_steering_limit
        self.sbus_steering_max = self.sbus_steering + self.sbus_steering_limit
        self.error = 0
        self.flag = True #For initializing pid params in loop()

        self.bot_mode = "manual"

        rospy.Subscriber("/sbus_rc_ch", Int32MultiArray, self.cmd_callback) # This is from the futaba
        rospy.Subscriber("/yaw", Float32, self.yaw_callback)




        rospy.init_node('tune_pid', anonymous=True)
        self.pub = rospy.Publisher('/sbus_cmd', Int32MultiArray, queue_size=10)
        self.sbus_cmd = Int32MultiArray()

        time.sleep(1)
        self.loop()
        rospy.spin()
        

    def cmd_callback(self,data):

        self.MODE = data.data[4]
        self.pid_reset_trigger = data.data[8]

    def reconfigure_callback(self,config):
        #rospy.loginfo("Config set to {P}, {I}, {D}, {bool_param}".format(**config))
        #print(config)
        self.p_new = config["P"]
        self.i_new = config["I"]
        self.d_new = config["D"]

    def yaw_callback(self,data):
        self.yaw = data.data

    def map_with_limit(self, val, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max):

        # out = ((val - in_min) * ((out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min))) + out_min
        ## in_min must be the minimum input 
        ## in_max must be the maximum input

        ## out_min is supposed to map with in_min value
        ## out_max is sipposed to map with in_max value
        ## out_min can be less/more than out_max, doesn't matter


        m = (out_max - out_min)/(in_max - in_min)
        out = m*(val - in_min) + out_min

        if out_min > out_max:
            if out > out_min:
                out = out_min
            elif out < out_max:
                out = out_max
            else:
                pass
        elif out_max > out_min:
            if out > out_max:
                out = out_max
            elif out < out_min:
                out = out_min
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass

        # print(m, val, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max)

        return out


    def loop(self):

        if self.flag:
            self.initial_angle = self.yaw
            ### PID Parameters ###
            self.p = 1
            self.i = 0
            self.d = 0
            flag_for_PID_setpoint = True
            if flag_for_PID_setpoint:
                self.setpoint = 0
                flag_for_PID_setpoint = False
            self.pid = PID(self.p, self.i, self.d, setpoint=self.setpoint)
            self.pid.tunings = (self.p, self.i, self.d)
            self.pid.sample_time = 0.001
            self.pid.output_limits = (-300, 300)
            self.flag = False

        #Dynamic reconfigure setup
        client = dynamic_reconfigure.client.Client("mypkg_node", timeout= 30, config_callback=self.reconfigure_callback)
        rate = rospy.Rate(30)

        while not rospy.is_shutdown():

            if self.MODE > 1900:
                self.bot_mode = "auto"
                #print(self.p)
                #print(self.i)
                #print(self.d)

            if self.MODE > 1000 and self.MODE < 1100:
                self.bot_mode = "manual" 

            if self.MODE < 1000:
                self.bot_mode = "hold"

            if self.pid_reset_trigger == 1024 or self.pid_reset_trigger == 1904:
                self.pid.reset()
                print("New values P: {}, I: {}, D:{}".format(self.p_new,self.i_new,self.d_new))
                #print(f"Resetting PID to new values {self.p_new} {self.i_new} {self.d_new}")
                self.pid = PID(self.p_new, self.i_new, self.d_new, setpoint=self.setpoint)
                self.pid.tunings = (self.p_new, self.i_new, self.d_new)
                self.pid.sample_time = 0.001
                self.pid.output_limits = (-300, 300)

            if self.bot_mode == "auto":
                #if self.initial_angle - self.yaw > 2 or self.initial_angle - self.yaw < -2:
                    #print("Going to start tuning now")
                self.diff = self.initial_angle -self.yaw  
                
                self.sbus_steering = self.pid(self.diff)
                self.sbus_steering = 1024 + self.sbus_steering
                print("Mode 1 "+ " diff: " +str(self.diff)+ " Setpoint: " +str(self.setpoint) + " Yaw "+str(self.yaw))
                #print(self.output_pid)
                #self.sbus_steering = int(self.map_with_limit(self.output_pid, -1.0, 1.0, self.sbus_steering_max, self.sbus_steering_min))
                self.sbus_cmd.data = [self.sbus_steering, self.sbus_throttle]
                rospy.loginfo("Steering: {}".format(self.sbus_steering))
                self.pub.publish(self.sbus_cmd)
            #print(self.bot_mode)
                # elif self.initial_angle - self.yaw <= 2 and self.initial_angle - self.yaw >= -2:
                #   self.sbus_steering = 1024
                #   self.sbus_cmd.data = [self.sbus_steering, self.sbus_throttle]
                #   self.pub.publish(self.sbus_cmd)
                #   print("Mode 2 "+ "Setpoint: "+ str(self.setpoint) + " Yaw "+str(self.yaw))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    object = PID_tuning()
```